# Why some commands are give different output when ran in Perl and in linux terminal

Tags: perl, unix, lsf, qx

When I run this command:

```
bjobs -r -P xenon -W | awk '{print $7}' | grep -v JOB_NAME |
cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs
```

in a terminal, all running JOB_NAMES are coming, but when I do this in per_script only JOB_ID are coming.

Perl script code is below:

```
@dummy_jobs = qx/bjobs -r -P xenon -W | awk '{print $7}' | grep -v JOB_NAME | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs/;
```

What needs to be changed in Perl?

Comment: I think `{print $7}` should be in double quotes not in single quotes

Comment: Check the output of the commend without `grep`

Comment: Perl is capable to __filter__ out the information of interest on it's own and you would not need to __pipe__ output of one command to other -- it would work much faster.

Comment: hm ... doesn't `awk '{print $7}'` print the seven-th _space_-delimited field of its input?  Then there is nothing for `-d' '` in `cut` as there are no spaces in what `cut` gets...?  And what is the pipe to `xargs` for? (Without arguments it only prints what it's given using `echo`)

Answer (score 3):

`qx/.../` literals are very much like double-quoted strings. Specifically, `$7` is interpolated, so you end up passing `... | awk '{print }' | ...`.

Replace

```perl
qx/...$7.../
```

with

```perl
qx/...\$7.../
```

Or if you prefer, you can use

```perl
my $shell_cmd = <<'EOS';  # These single-quotes means you get exactly what follows.
bjobs -r -P xenon -W | awk '{print $7}' | grep -v JOB_NAME | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs
EOS

my @dummy_jobs = qx/$shell_cmd/;
```

---

Another difference is that `qx` uses `/bin/sh` instead of whatever shell you were using, but that shouldn't be relevant here.